# How to hide XMLHttpRequests from console in Firebug lite on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, firebug-lite

I have installed Firebug lite as a bookmarklet in Safari on iPad. While debugging there are a lot of XMLHttpRequests records in the console.

How to switch Firebug Lite to not show such messages? I cannot find *Show XMLHttpRequests* option like it is in general Firebug extension for Firefox.

Thanks!